# Form tag inside tbody not working

Tags: forms, angular, html-table

I have a table. It has a row which have input fields as table cell. But when form is loaded inside the table it appears in a single cell of table instead of whole row.

[Here is the plunker eg](https://plnkr.co/edit/ksHmrYWBtpbOI1kVsyhe?p=preview)

Child Component which has form:

```
<form [formGroup]="dependentForm">
  <td>
    <input type="text" size="10" formControlName="first">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" size="10" formControlName="last">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" size="10" formControlName="dob">
  </td>
</form>
```

Parent Component which loads child:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First</th>
      <th>Last</th>
      <th>DOB</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody dependent-row></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That's invalid HTML. You can't have any other tag than `<tr>` and `<template>` inside `<tbody>`

Comment: Two ways I see you could go here. 1st: Use divs and css to mimic your table, instead of a real table. This allows for what you are trying to achive. 2nd: If possible, put the <form> start and closing tags around the whole table, which should work too.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't need to use a `<form>` element. Just add `ngForm` or `formGroup` to the `<tr>`

```
<tr ngForm>
```

or

```
<tr [ngFormGroup]="myForm"
```

not tried myself yet though